# Laravel : Middleware Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I have middleware **UKM** I want if the `Auth::id()` in the table `ukm`, hen can access the next request. But not working, if `Auth::id()` no in the table user can access.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $query = DB::table('ukm')->where('id_user',Auth::id())->get();

    foreach($query as $key){
        $cek = $key->id_user;
    }

    if ($cek != NULL) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: What happens if you `dump($cek);` just before `return $next($request);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $query = DB::table('ukm')->where('id_user',Auth::id())->first();
    if ($query != NULL) {
        return $next($request);
    }

        return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this ....

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $query = DB::table('ukm')->pluck('id_user')->toArray();

          if(in_array( Auth::user()->id, $query )
             {
               return $next($request);
             }

        return redirect('/');
    }
```